# Unable to post uploaded file from HTML to AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to upload a file using AngularJS, but I am unable to get the file in ng-controller. It is showing as undefined. Below is the HTML and AngualrJS code. Please help.

```html
<form id="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" data-ng-submit="uploadFile()">
  <p>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="file" file-model="myFile" />
    </div>
  </p>
  <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

```js
'use strict';

var UploadFileController = angularApp
  .controller(
    'UploadFileController',
    function UploadFileController($scope, $rootScope,
      UserDataService, $http, $location, $window,
      UtilService, CommonDataService, ControllerService) {

      $scope.uploadFile = function() {
        var nameFile = $scope.myFile;
        console.log("Uploaded file====>>> ", nameFile);

      };

      $scope.init = function() {
        console.log("Upload Controller InitApp");
      }

      angular.element(document).ready(function() {
        $scope.init();

      });


    });
```

Comment: Your code is working fine. The only wrong thing I could imagine is your didn't include the module `file-model` (https://github.com/ghostbar/angular-file-model).

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks a lot